# Reads a line break at the end of the user input in c

Tags: c, printf, user-input, getline

So, I am trying to read user input using getline and the error I am having is that, if the user enters "Hi there", when it reads this it thinks there is a line break at the end. So when I try to print it, it prints "Hi there" and then automatically goes to the next line, how can I make it not go to the next line.

Here is my code -

```
printf(">");
getline(&userinput,&length,stdin);
printf("userinput:%s",userinput);
printf("DONE");
```

if the user enters - "Is it done?"

It currently prints this -

```
"Is it done?"
"DONE"
```

But I want it to print - `"Is it done?DONE"`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to eliminate the line break from the userinput string:

```
printf(">");
getline(&userinput,&length,stdin);

char *cp=strchr(userinput, '\n');  /* Find the line-break character (if it exists) */
if(cp)
   *cp = '\0';  /* Convert the line-break character to a string termination character. */

printf("userinput:%s",userinput);
printf("DONE");
```

Answer (score 0):

`getline` included the newline character. You can trim that by:

```
userinput[strlen(userinput)-1] = '\0';
```

Then, you can print both of them using:

```
printf("userinput: %s DONE\n", userinput);
```

Comment: `getline()` returns the number of characters written to the buffer, also, so you could use that and eliminate the need for the `strlen()` call.